# How to fast check a edge of a directed graph is a strong bridge

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am looking for an algorithm just to determine if a given edge is a strong bridge or not, for a directed graph.
I know the algorithm to find all strong bridges(Giuseppe F. Italiano, Luigi Laura, Federico Santaroni: Finding strong bridges and strong articulation points in linear time. Theor. Comput. Sci. 447: 74-84 (2012).
Is any faster algorithm to check single edge?

Comment: Try better asking in cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: You may have to walk the whole graph to determine even if two adjacent vertexes are in the same SCC, because the edge that creates a cycle may be the last one you look at.  So there can't be an algorithm for this that is better than linear time in the worst case

Comment: I don't know the algorithm which you have mentioned, but I would expect that there are no algorithms to find strong bridges in a graph which are faster than **linear time**. As far as I know, you only need to count strong connectivity components count, remove this edge and count them again. If there are more components after your remove an edge, then it is a strong bridge.